# BCC in Mailgun Batch Send does not include substitutions

Tags: python, mailgun, mailing-list, bcc

I am sending a set of email messages via Mailgun using the Batch Sending feature of their API, with a call like this:

```
rv = requests.post(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/%s/messages" % mailgun_domain,
    auth=("api", mailgun_key),
    data={"from": sender,
        "to": recip_vars.keys(),
        "subject": subject,
        "bcc": bcc_addr,
        "text": "%recipient.text%",
        "html": "%recipient.html%",
        "recipient-variables":json.dumps(recip_vars)})
```

where `recip_vars` is a dictionary of the batch variables keyed by recipient addresses.

In the copy sent to the `bcc` address, the `recip_vars` substitution has not been made.

Does the `bcc` address need to be specified in a different way in order for that copy to include the substitutions, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the good people at Mailgun, this is not possible, at least in the current release of the service.

Comment: just spoke with maligun support and unfortunately this is still the case. if it's an issue for you then goto https://feedback.mailgun.com/forums/156243-feature-requests?query=bcc%20 if they get enough feedback they may implement it!